# In array map iterator, how to get value concatenate state and array map id

Tags: reactjs

I have several images fetched from a server, then I have rendered them with array map helper along with file input to upload images.
When I select a file, I want to replace it with the actual image in place.

I have initialized a state store selected images and set values onChage event.  In the jsx, I set image url in ternary operator based on the state value.

```
  function App() { 
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState(null);
  const [upload, setUpload] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=0&_limit=2')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => setPhotos(json))
  }, [])

  const handleChange = e => {
    setUpload({...upload, [e.currentTarget.name]: URL.createObjectURL(e.currentTarget.files[0])});  
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      { photos ? photos.map(photo => (
          <div key={photo.id}>
            <div>
                {upload ? <img src={upload.photo_+photo.id} alt="" /> : <img src={photo.thumbnailUrl} alt="" /> }
            </div>
              <input type="file" name={`photo_${photo.id}`} onChange={handleChange} /><br /><br />
          </div>
        )) : <div>Loading...</div>
       }
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I select an image, nothing happening, the actual image should be replaced.

Comment: log photos so we can see your data structure

Comment: Photos fetched from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=0&_limit=2, component renders them, here is code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-euclid-b2d6u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
upload['photo_' + photo.id]
```

also I'd use this

```
{photos ? photos.map(photo => <Child photo={photo} key={photo.id} />) : <div>Loading...</div>}
```

So eventually the app should looks like

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=0&_limit=2")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setPhotos(json));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {photos ? photos.map(photo => <Child photo={photo} key={photo.id} />) : <div>Loading...</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = ({ photo }) => {
  const [upload, setUpload] = useState(null);
  const handleChange = e => {
    setUpload(URL.createObjectURL(e.currentTarget.files[0]));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {upload ? (
          <img src={upload} alt="" />
        ) : (
          <img src={photo.thumbnailUrl} alt="" />
        )}
      </div>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much Eugene Glova, it's woking.